# cordova build error : failed to find ANDROID_HOME variable, and android in your PATH

Tags: android, cordova, build

I already set these variables:

echo $ANDROID_HOME => /usr/local/android-sdk-linux

echo $PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

But this same error remains when I execute "cordova build android" or "cordova run android --device":

Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory

Do you have any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and what helped me solve the problem is removing the android platform from your cordova project and re-adding it.

```
cordova platform rm android

cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/), and installing the platform. It should end up in the top level of your user's directory. `export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk`, so you can try that.